# How can make header sticky in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

This is my the link of website http://www.expresskerala.com. In this website i need to make header sticky. Is there any way to make that sticky.I had tried this code.

```
.site-header {
    background: #e5e5e5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99 !important;
}
```

But when i use this code, the other content will go down. Is there any solution for this. This should be also responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `position:fixed` element is taken out of the document flow, you need to add a top margin equal to the height of the `.site-header` to the next element. You also need to add `top:0` to fix the `.site-header` to the top of the document.

```
.site-header {
    background: #e5e5e5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99 !important;
    top: 0;
}
.site-header + * {
    margin-top: 240px; 
    // you should change this using media queries if the site-header height changes
}
```

Comment: .site-header + *   (+ * means?)

Comment: It means "any element immediately following `.site-header`"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .site-header {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #main > .container {
        padding-top: 250px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add these css to get better result

```
body {
    padding-top: 240px;
}


.site-header {
    background: #e5e5e5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this additional css in your file

```
.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

than use also this script:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 140) {
       $('nav').addClass('fixed-header');
    }
    else {
       $('nav').removeClass('fixed-header');
    }
});

/* scrollTop() >= 140
   Should be equal the height of the header
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 240) {
       $('body').addClass('sticky-header');
    }
    else {
       $('body').removeClass('sticky-header');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
 body.sticky-header {
        padding-top: 239px;
    }
    body.sticky-header header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 999
    }
    header {
        transition:all ease .3s
    }
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score -1):

Use sticky position [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)or use jquery with fixed